# How to compile a C source file that uses make file, from command prompt?

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, makefile, command-prompt

I want to compile a C source file from command prompt that draws a triangle using openGL. I have the gcc compiler installed. The source file that I want to compile and execute is binded with something called **Makefile.win32** file.

In my computer's *F:* drive there is a folder called **opengl_codes**. Inside that folder there are a bunch of files and two folders called **hello_triangle** and **common**.

Inside the *hello_triangle* folder I have these files :  **main.c** and **Makefile.win32**.

I read a bunch of tutorials in the internet about Makefile, found out that to compile and execute the c source file I have to do this :-
1.first execute `make -f Makefile.win32` in command prompt from the containing directory.
2.then compile the source file. i.e. `gcc -o main.exe main.c`

But when I execute the first command i.e. `make -f Makefile.win32`I get this error :-

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -o hellot.exe main.c -I ../common/include ../common/win32/libglew32.dll.a ../common/win32/glfw3dll.a -lOpenGL32 -L ./ -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lm
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglew32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am not understanding what is causing this error.

Makefile :-

```
BIN = hellot.exe
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -Wall -pedantic
INC = -I ../common/include
LOC_LIB = ../common/win32/libglew32.dll.a ../common/win32/glfw3dll.a
SYS_LIB = -lOpenGL32 -L ./ -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lm
SRC = main.c

all:
    ${CC} ${FLAGS} -o ${BIN} ${SRC} ${INC} ${LOC_LIB} ${SYS_LIB}
```

Comment: You no longer need to add `-lglew32` and `-lglfw3` since you're explicitly linking with `../common/win32/libglew32.dll.a` and `../common/win32/glfw32dll.a`

Comment: @JohnMarkCaguicla I haven't added any library manually.

Comment: Well then you should edit your Makefile to not include `-lglew32` and `-lglfw3`. By the way are you using anything (IDE, CMake) to generate the Makefile?

Comment: @JohnMarkCaguicla no, the Makefiles for windows and other operating systems are already there in the hello_triangle folder.

Comment: If the corresponding libraries are in `../common/win32/` then you should edit the Makefile and remove `-lglew32 -lglfw3`. If not get & install those libraries, and instead remove the `../common/win32/*` entry on the Makefile

Comment: @JohnMarkCaguicla In the common/win32/ folder I have these libraries - glfw3dll.a, libglew32.dll.a, freetype.lib, assimp.lib. Should I edit the Makefile?

Comment: Yes, you need to remove `-lglew32` and `-lglfw3` since you already have the `../common/win32/*` entries.

Comment: @JohnMarkCaguicla I pasted the makefile's code. Can you tell me which line should I remove?

Comment: Make it like `SYS_LIB = -lOpenGL32 -L ./ -lm`